# Intersection of two regex's

Tags: regex, regular-language, finite-automata, dfa, nfa

Thanks for any help in advance!

I am taking an automata course at school and for the life of me cannot work out the intersection of two regex's. I have looked online and on here, to find that I can create NFA's for both languages, compliment them individually then union(ise) - unsure on english here.

Following this, I then compliment the union to find the subsequent DFA and find the regex from that, which would be the intersection regex. However, it is the calculation of all this that I am struggling with.

I have a question below, where I have changed the expressions as to not simply ask a tutorial question. Both are over the same alphabet: `{a,b,c,d}`.

Let `R1 = (a(a+d))*` and `R2 = ((a+b)+a+(a+d))*`

I have expanded the languages to try and understand them better.

Thoughts: 
R1 contains the empty word (epsilon), and words of length 2 and 4
R2 contains the empty word, and words of length 3

The subsequent intersection language must be divisible by 6?

I genuinely do not know how to proceed from here. Please can someone help me create a NFA if this would be the best approach. I have used online NFA generators but keep making mistakes when I look back at the universities tutorial answers. On a side note, how would you prove the regex you calculate is correct?

Thank you!

Comment: Isn't R1 equivalent to `(a(a+d))*`? Also, it's "complement".

Comment: Ahh, good point. I will remove the final ad now. Thank you.

Comment: I just realized I don't understand your notation. What does `+` mean?

Comment: I believe that `(a+b)` is the equivalent of `(a|b)`.

Comment: Then R2 is `(a+b+d)*`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple DFA for R1:

[image: DFA for R1]

R2=(a|b|d)* as @melpomene said in his comment, which means any word with letters a,b or d so a DFA for R2 is obviously:

[image: eDFA for R2]

The intersection is  R1 (as R2 is every body with a, b or d)

We can complete this DFA like this:

[image: DFA for intersection]